# Placing button on image hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know i'll get lot of solutions with similar name. But my problem is - My code is working offline . but i put it online... it's not showing any button on image hover. Here is the code..[code](http://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/P3Ew6/398/)

2- Issue- i want to remove middle show class outside image. while its removing the class when my mouse in the location of my button... Thanks

i am happy to replace my jquery with css... but dont want to change html..

```css
img:hover{
opacity:0.5;
background-color:#000;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.middleShow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" align="left"><img src="https://seedroid.com/img/post/icons/128/csdevbin.arham.naturelivewallpaper.jpg" alt="Custom photo wall art of a white perspex box frame of a couple on the beach with a red scarf" width="100%">
        <div class="middle">
         <div class="text">Close Look</div>
        </div>
      
  <h2><a href="/acrylic-box/">Any Text</a></h2>
    <p class="LeeFont">Gbvdcgfn vhgd ghguj gfhjg bn .</p></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: we cant access to your code. so please add your code here

Comment: Sorry, Original code is here http://jsfiddle.net/shreya_js/P3Ew6/399/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not really that the button doesn't show, the button does show (or could if the transition attributes were different), but at present, because the opacity is 0, the button appears not to show, and .6s is not long enough for a user to move to the button and click it. You can make a minor adjustment to your code to the [duration/delay](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) times of the transition to correct this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings("div.middle").addClass("middleShow");
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings("div.middle").removeClass("middleShow");
    });
});
```

```css
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #000;
}

.middle {
  transition: opacity .6s ease 1.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.middleShow {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" align="left"><img src="https://seedroid.com/img/post/icons/128/csdevbin.arham.naturelivewallpaper.jpg" alt="Custom photo wall art of a white perspex box frame of a couple on the beach with a red scarf" width="100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">Close Look</div>
      </div>

      <h2><a href="/acrylic-box/">Any Text</a></h2>
      <p class="LeeFont">Gbvdcgfn vhgd ghguj gfhjg bn .</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code will ease-in after .6s and stay on screen for 1.5 seconds. Adjust as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, But button is showing when i check offline even you can see on fiddle as well... but the problem is when i upload my code i cannot see my button but its exist on page ..

Comment: The button appears in the fiddle I created and the snippet.

Comment: yes i know its apppear on fiddle... but not in my website... :-(

Comment: Adjust the CSS for your transition as suggested. If it still doesn't show, then the button is being affected by other code

Comment: The duration is a problem as I see it. Add the second at the end (or 2)

Comment: Also, you could try giving it a high z-index. This is another possible reason why you can't see it.

Comment: I am using this css at this moment . and it does not have any transition ....img:hover{
opacity:0.5;
background-color:#000;
}

.middle {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #934391;
   padding: 14px 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.middleShow {
  opacity: 1;
}

Comment: You have no transition in the middle! Add it ...if you don't add the transition, the opacity will stay at 0 and you won't be able to see the button , ever!

Comment: Rachel... in my page i have 9 images... when i'll move my mouse inside image it'll show a text/button (see more) .. and on mouse out button will disappear... and when we clicked on button it will open another page.. see Example : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity

Comment: problem appears after uploading my code.. as i mentioned above it's not working when i am putting my code online... and i don't know why??? Thanks for help

Comment: Check the link to your CSS file and your image files.